# Firestore rules, what is a collection and a document?

Tags: firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I mean I know what those are but I am a bit confuse about the security rules, for example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // This is probably a mistake
    match /spaceships { // <= what is this a collection or a document?
      allow read;
      // In spite of the above line, a user can't read any document within the 
      // spaceship collection.
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase documentation says:

> Rules for collections don't apply to documents within that collection. It's unusual (and probably an error) to have a security rule that is written at the collection level instead of the document level.

That means that this `match /spaceships {...` is a collection right?

But later on we have this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**}{ // <= what is this a document or a collection?
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand is this `match /{document=**}{...` a document? or a collection? I mean is at the collection level.

Answer (score 9):

Paths in Firestore are alternating collections and documents: `/collection/document/subcollection/subdocument`

For example:

```
// Matches kaylee, the mechanic on serenity
/spaceships/serenity/crew/kaylee/...
```

When using security rules, you can specify wildcards:

```
// This will match any spaceship, and any crewmember
/spaceships/{spaceshipId}/crew/{crewmemberId}/...
```

Now imagine that you have another subcollection under `spaceships`:

```
/spaceships/{spaceshipId}/stowaways/{stowawayId}/...
```

If you want to write rules against multiple subcollections, you need to either:

```
// You could use multiple single wildcards
/spaceships/{spaceshipId}/{crewOrStowaway}/{crewOrStowawayId}/...

// Or you could use a multi-segment wildcard
/spaceships/{spaceshipId}/{allShipInformation=**}
```

This returns `allShipInformation` as a path, which will match all documents *and* collections at and below that path. Note that it's one or more path segment, rather than zero or more.

You can read more about this [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#using_wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

In your first example `/spaceships` is at the collection level. As was stated in the quote you referenced, placing a rule here is not helpful as it won't be applied to any of the documents in the collection.

In your second example `/{document=**}` is at the collection level but is using a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#recursive_matching_with_wildcards). In short, what this does is apply the rule to the documents within this collection and to any documents within any subcollections of this collection.

This allows you to write:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**}{
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /spaceships/{shipId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /spaceships/{shipId}/crew/{crewMemberId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```